# SBS Journal Wrap Condition

Tags: exchange-2003, windows-sbs-2003, windows-sbs

When I run the SBS Best Practices Analyzer on my SBS 2003 R2, it says I have a 'journal wrap condition'. What does that mean and how can it be repaired?

Answer (score 2):

That is something that you want to fix...  If you take a look at your event logs, you will probably see a corresponding event 13568 that has instructions on fixing the error.

For more information, check out the following posts:

http://msmvps.com/blogs/bradley/archive/2007/12/26/fixing-a-little-bit-of-journal-wrap.aspx
http://msmvps.com/blogs/bradley/archive/2007/12/27/help-i-ve-lost-my-sysvol-and-can-t-get-up.aspx
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290762/en-us

-Sean

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to clear your event viewer logs for File Replication Service.  This is where the analyzer or the migration tool checks.  We fixed the error but couldn't continue with migration until we cleared these events from the Event Viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.windows.server.sbs&tid=2079e229-4fbf-4d77-b98d-0d4e33c7948f&cat=en_US_77750084-cabb-4056-9708-d9264353c1b3&lang=en&cr=US&sloc=&p=1) out in the MS newsgroups.  Looks like it's not that big of a deal.

Comment: It is if you want to do a SBS03->SBS08 migration